# A newbie question on the basics concerning Hausdorff space, topology and definitions.

Tags: general-topology

I'm learning about topological spaces and note that they come in flavours with more or less restrictions and structure. A Hausdorff space is defined as a topological space where there's some open domain separating each of the elements.
What I fail to understand concerning this definition is if the separating sets of elements in an Hausdorff space (set X,topology T) are part of the same Hausdorff space topology T, or is it enough that they just belong to a neighbourhood to X with some other topology K?

Is the property of separation in a Hausdorff space a property of T? Ie is the restriction of elements in X expressed as a topology? If not, how can I think of this specialisation (?) of a topological space, ie what is it I do when I construct a Hausdorff from a lesser Topological space?

Comment: I would say, that it a property of the **pair** $(X,T)$: For all **$x,y\in X$** with $x\neq y$ there are **$A,B\in T$** disjoint with $x\in A$ and $y\in B$. However, the underlying set $X$ can be recovered from $T$, e.g., as the union of all sets which are elements of $T$.

Answer (score 1):

Those "open domains" that you are mentioning in the definition depend on the topology you are working. As an illustration, take a two elements set $X=\{ a,b\}.$ Then the discrete space (the discrete topology is $\tau_1=\{ X,\emptyset , \{ a\},\{ b\} \}$) is Hausdorff, but the indiscrete space(the indiscrete topology is $\tau_1=\{ X,\emptyset \}$) is not.